# How do I generate a python GUI using an XML based layout of the GUI?

Tags: python, xml, user-interface, themes, skin

I designed a customized UI in Photoshop and now I would like to use XML to create and GUI for python. I saw this website http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=WindowXML and they use WindowXML GUI Toolkit to create customized GUI.

Has someone achieved this? where can I get more info?

I have heard of Qt and wxPython but  All the examples I have found can be easily achieved with Tkinter.

Please answer this question with some examples and(or) details. I know that many python (newbie) programmers are looking for something like this.

Answer (score 4):

I think [glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) outputs the GUI construction as an XML file which can then be translated into Python (or other languages). You can use the Glade constructor directly to design the GUI but since you've already done it using Photoshop, you can try to write the layout in the same schema that glade outputs. Once you do that, the glade toolchain should be able to convert it into Python for you.

Comment: Does Glade convert to tkinter? Or some other GUI binding?

Comment: Not that I know of. It's GTK specific.

Answer (score 2):

Not XML, but QT supports [QML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML), which is a concise Javascript based way of doing some declarative layouts of GUIs:

```
 Item {
     Rectangle {
         id: myRect
         width: 100
         height: 100
     }
     Rectangle {
         width: myRect.width
         height: 200
     }
 }
```

Here's a QML [tutorial](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/tutorials/qmladvancedtutorial/) using PySide (a QT library for Python).

Comment: QML does not support classic QT widgets.

Answer (score 0):

I found this interesting [blog](https://www.nohuddleoffense.de/2011/04/20/generating-tkinter-guis-from-xml/) about writing tkinter applications using xml:

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34536490)

Comment: I will update my answer as soon as I have solid feedback. Just mentioned it here to keep track of and return to it later. To be continued...