# parse XML file into a GUI in Python

Tags: python, xml, user-interface

I'm working on a project - I want to view XML data in convenient way.
I created XML file with data and I want to view the data by tables.

For example - for this XML file:

```
<events>
  <event>
    <date> 23/12/2014</date>
    <time>20:18:01</time>
    <text>blabla</text>
  </event>
</events>
```

I would like to get simple GUI that present the data by tables - by reading the XML data:

```
|#|text  |time    |date       |
|1|blabla|20:18:01| 23/12/2014|
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question might be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11702071/1076075

Comment: How to use Glade to create GUI from the XML?

Comment: I haven't done that before, but this looks promising... http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/builder.html

Answer (score 0):

I mannge to do it myself.
XML and HTML file are very similar.
I replaced some words and got HTML tables page.

```
events->table
event->tr
date/time/text->td
(added HTML tags)
```

the result is HTML page that present the information in very convenient way.